# Laravel 5.2 Select Where Has Related Count Data

Tags: laravel, filter

I have a table called 'templates' and 'details' that has relation templates has many details at my model.

i create a list template table with a filter number or detail, when i input 5 to the filter box, then table only show the templates that has 5 details.

how to do this?

this is my table structure :

**templates**

id   | name          | width          | heigh

1    | A-5           | 112            | 100

2    | A-4           | 225            | 200

**details**

template_id       | x           | y

1                 | 10          | 10

1                 | 20          | 10

2                 | 10          | 10

2                 | 20          | 10

```
$templates = Template::whereHas( 'details', function( $detail ) {
    $detail->selectRaw( 'count(id) as aduh' )->whereRaw( 'count(id) = 100' )->groupBy( 'id' );
} );
```

Comment: Is *details* a column in your table? Can you add your tables structure and what result you expect to get?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
$templates = Template::has('details', '=', 5)->get();
```

This will return all *Templates* that has 5 *details*.